# Return most frequently occurring value/row from a for loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I have a for loop that returns ID's of a list of products contained in a customer's order. Each product ID is associated with a category via a function I cannot modify, and I wanted to get a single category that occurs the most in the returned results.

For example the for loop result returns product IDs: 1 2 3 4

And subsequently those product IDs would be associated with categories: A B B C

How would I return 'B' only, being that it is the most frequently occurring category?

```
for ($i = 0, $n = sizeof($order->products); $i < $n; $i++) {
    $products = $order->products[$i]['id'];
    echo $products; //return all products
    echo category_name($products); //this function returns all the category names of each ID, but I only want to return the most frequently occurring one without modifying this function
}
```

Comment: Note: I cannot modify the category_name function that associates product IDs to categories.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to assign them to an array and then `array_count_values`:

```
for ($i = 0, $n = sizeof($order->products); $i < $n; $i++) {
    $products = $order->products[$i]['id'];
    echo $products;
    echo $categories[] = category_name($products); //assign to array
}

$result = array_count_values($categories);
arsort($result);
echo $result[0];
```

If you have more than one category that appears the same number of maximum times then the one appearing last in the array will be returned.

I would use a `foreach`:

```
foreach($order->products as $product) {
    echo $product['id'];
    echo $categories[] = category_name($product['id']); //assign to array
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I seem to be having an error of an infinite loop. `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given` Could it be related to the object operator of ->?

Comment: That's no where in the code you posted.  That means you had a query fail somewhere.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems to be only happening when I run the array_count_values function... which suggests that it is not a valid array?

Comment: Dunno dude.  Has nothing to do with `mysql_fetch_array()`.